# jQuery, draggable, container id

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in jQuery...

```
$("#sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        var colNum = $(ui.item).attr("id").replace(/col_/, "");
        $.post("/Category/Insert", { title: colNum });
    },
```

the var colNum = $(ui.... )
this gets the id from the item being dragged. I was wondering, is it possible for me to get the id of the container it is being dropped in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the dropped item is inside and direct descendant of the container, you can access the container using the `parent()` method:

```
var parent_id = $(ui.item).parent().attr('id');
```